# How can I check if a warning was raised but still not to turn it into an exception

Tags: python

I have a method `get_font` that can raise a `DefaultFontWarning`. I want to check if that warning was raised and to run a piece of code if it's the case.

My current solution is

```
def set_font(self):
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.filterwarnings("error")
        try:
            self.font = get_font(self.path, self.size)
        except DefaultFontWarning:
            self.is_default = True
```

This attaches `is_default` to `self`, but it also silences the warning so that user cannot see it.

How can I check if a warning was raised but still not to turn it into an exception and output it?

Comment: Can't you re-raise it again?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes, but then the traceback is ugly. During handling `E`, `E` was rised.

Comment: If you capture it with `except DefaultFontWarning as w:`, you should be able to display it with `warnings.warn(w)`

Comment: Your wording is unclear. Do you want to output an exception or a warning?

Comment: @ZachGates a warning

Answer (score 1):

Raise a `Warning` (or another type; such as `UserWarning`), but retain the original traceback.

```
def set_font(self):
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        try:
            self.font = get_font(self.path, self.size)
        except DefaultFontWarning as e:
            raise Warning(*e.args).with_traceback(e.__traceback__) from None
```

Using `from None` will effectively get rid of the `During handling ...` message. You can use your own message such as `'bad font'` by replacing `*e.args`:

```
raise Warning('bad font').with_traceback(e.__traceback__) from None
```